# Is there any harm in modelling Likert scale data using an lmer() model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, likert

I have 140 participants, each making 70 ratings. The DV is a seven-item Likert scale.

I've read conflicting things about modeling this sort of data with a plain lmer() model.

I'm curious what the current consensus is?

Comment: What is the purpose of your model ?

Comment: @RobertLong I have some independent variables and I want to see if they predict the outcome.

Answer (score 4):

Since your goal with the model is prediction and not inference, I don't think there is any harm in modelling a 7-point Likert scale outcome as continuous with lmer. I would, however suggest comparing it with other approaches such as cumulative link mixed model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd actually say that my interests are more in inference rather than prediction. I assume the advice would then be to try a cumulative link mixed model?